# Textchanged in VB.net does not display results in my gridview

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, gridview

I am using this code and i always get no display in my gridview, at first it loads, it shows all the records i have,but when i use the textchange property i always dont get the list that i wanted

Here is my first code for the load of data and it works fine

```
Public Sub LoadDataPI()
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = <SQL>SELECT CDate as 'Date', AName as 'Applicant', DPosition as 'Position', Address, Gender, Telephone, Cellphone, Email, Bdate as 'Birthdate', CStatus as 'Civil Status', Height, Weight, Religion, Spouse FROM tbl_applicant </SQL>

    Dim myadap As New MySqlDataAdapter(mycom)
    Dim mydt As New DataTable

    myadap.Fill(mydt)
    grdApplicantsPI.DataSource = mydt
    myadap.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Here is my second code which i edited to make it simple

```
Private Sub txtSearchBar1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearchBar1.TextChanged
    myr.Close()
    grdApplicantsPI.Refresh()
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = <SQL>SELECT CDate as 'Date',AName as 'Applicant Name' FROM tbl_applicant where AName LIKE '%"  txtSearchBar1.Text  "%'</SQL>

    Dim myadap As New MySqlDataAdapter(mycom)
    Dim mydt As New DataTable

    myadap.Fill(mydt)
    grdApplicantsPI.DataSource = mydt
    myadap.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Can anyone suggest a solution i just want to display the records in my database in the gridview whit a basis of text that i would input in the textbox

Comment: Please edit the question and add details of the error you are getting. Also at the end of the SQL you have no condition applied to the EmerContact field.

Comment: Don't you need `grdApplicantsPI.Databind` after you specify the `Datasource`?

Comment: i dont know, i just cant figure out how to get the results @NP3

Comment: So please add `grdApplicantsPI.DataBind()` after the line `grdApplicantsPI.DataSource = mydt` and check if you get results in the grid.

Comment: i get this error when i input the code    `DataBind is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'` @NP3

Comment: don't use quote in alias use backtick it is located before the number 1,2,3,4.. and the lower button of esc

Comment: it still wont work :(

Comment: Try with a `BindingSource` as in this MSDN help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @NP3 thanks for your link but it doesnt produce the right output

Comment: Are you using UpdatePanel of asp.net and grid is placed inside update panel, if yes call updatePanel.update() method after binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing your command to this... In yours, you forgot the "&" to include your textfield, so your basically ommitting everything as, (Select * where name like txtSearchBar1.Text) you wont return anything that is unless indeed theres a name matching "txtSearchBar1.Text" as a record.

```
 "SELECT CDate as 'Date',AName as 'Applicant Name' FROM tbl_applicant WHERE AName LIKE '%" & txtSearchBar1.Text & "%'"
```