# Change the Column name of gridview using VB.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, gridview

The column names of my gridview follows the column name of my table in my database.
is there anyway i can modify their column names in the gridview without changing the column names my database table??

```
Public Sub LoadDataPI()
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = <SQL>SELECT CDate,AName,DPosition,Address,Gender,Telephone,Cellphone,Email,Bdate,CStatus,Height,Weight,Religion,Spouse,SOccupation,FName,FOccupation,MName,MOccupation,EmerName,EmerAddress,EmerContact FROM tbl_applicant </SQL>

    Dim myadap As New MySqlDataAdapter(mycom)
    Dim mydt As New DataTable

    myadap.Fill(mydt)
    grdApplicantsPI.DataSource = mydt
    myadap.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use alias something as `select CDate as Date, AName as Name ...` this way you do not need to change the column names in the DB.

Comment: nope it doesnt work the way you eXplained
    '#420000 You have an error in your sql syntax near  'Name,DPosition as Desired Position,Address,Gender,Telephone,Cellphone,Email,Bdat' at line 1'

Comment: use backtick like this  `select CDate as ``Date``, AName as ``Name`` maybe because you have alias name of reserved word

Comment: what do you mean backtick? @CodeSlayer

Comment: (`) this is backtick but currently this is un available to show because of this site..just add backtick before and after the alias name

Comment: @CodeSlayer try to answer my question and ill approve your answer

Comment: @CodeSlayer     can you help me with this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031373/textchanged-in-vb-net-does-not-display-results-in-my-gridview?noredirect=1#comment42589882_27031373

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DataGridView then you can use the HeaderText property in Columns collection of this control:

```
'grdApplicantsPI.Columns(<column index>).HeaderText = "New text"
grdApplicantsPI.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Nº"
```

or

```
'grdApplicantsPI.Columns(<column name>).HeaderText = "New text"
grdApplicantsPI.Columns("ID").HeaderText = "Nº"
```

Comment: even your suggestion didnt work, on the first one it says its index was out of range, AND THE NEXT ONE STATES that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: because first you need assign the DataSource: ***grdApplicantsPI.DataSource = mydt*** (LoadDataPI) and only after of **LoadDataPI** you can changing the names of columns, for example: ***grdApplicantsPI.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Nº"***.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that, I prefer the first, because has less lines of code...

1. Change your SELECT Query to include the "AS" statement in your query...

   ```
    mycom.CommandText = <SQL>SELECT CDate AS "Commencement Date", AName AS "Name", DPosition AS "Director Position", Address, Gender, Telephone, Cellphone, Email, Bdate, CStatus, Height, Weight, Religion, Spouse, SOccupation, FName AS "First Name", FOccupation, MName, MOccupation, EmerName, EmerAddress, EmerContact FROM tbl_applicant </SQL>
   ```
2. Change the Headers in the Datagridview *(After filling the Datagridview) because the names come from the datatable (you might also want to hide unnecessary columns)...

   ```
    grdApplicantsPI.Columns["CDate"].HeaderText = "Commencement Date"
    grdApplicantsPI.Columns["FName"].HeaderText = "First Name"
    grdApplicantsPI.Columns["EmerName"].Visible = false 'hiding a column
   ```